# what are the different ways to specify the values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a question regarding the value initialization

- In query tool:

  ```
  Insert into tablename(field1, field2, field3..) 
  values (value1, value2, value3..);
  ```
- In my JavaScript code, I am using:

  ```
  db.query({ text: 'INSERT INTO tablename(field1, field2, field3) 
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', values: [value 1 , value 2 , value 3'] }).then(...)
  ```
- is this a good practice?

  ```
  select * from tablename where _id="+[value]+" AND field1 = "+[value]+";
  ```

I have listed 3 query above. As per my knowledge 1 & 2 are right as I tried them in many of my projects. Can someone clarify is the option 3 is also a correct method? Does it match the standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1 is the basic "insert .. values" syntax and works well.

Of course, you *should* be using Parameterised Queries/ Prepared Statement to avoid SQL Injection Attacks and to simplify Data Type conversions.

Number 2 extends Number 1, inserting the values and returning those self-same values that were just inserted which is, in my opinion, a  *bit* pointless, because you just supplied the values to be inserted and so you already know what they are.

Number 3, is simply treating the SQL as text and doing string replacements to get the parameter values in there.  This is downright risky, leaving you exposed to SQL Injection attacks.

It's *possible* that you're using some package or other (you mention a "query tool") and, if so, that might "handle" this format and do the substitutions on your behalf.  If that's the case then you can *hope* that you're in a better position but you're completely reliant on the suppliers of this package getting their code *absolutely* right and *never* forgetting that all-important control-character escaping.

Parameterised Queries/ Prepared Statements are definitely the recommended way to go.

Obligatory XKCD Reference: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Regards,   Phill  W.

Comment: `RETURNING *` returns all the values (from all the columns), even the columns not included in the VALUES list (autogenerated serials, timestamps, anything with a default value/expression)

Answer (score 4):

If the values are obtained from a user input, 2) and 3) are a bad idea.

You shouldn't put user supplied values directly into the SQL string, but use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with bind variables. Not doing that, makes your application vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

*How* you use a prepared statement with bind variables depends on the programming language you are using.